# Objective C Make message to nil generate run time error

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to make messages sent to nil generate some sort of error in run time? I want it for the debugging purpose.

Comment: Now's the time to get used to nil messaging. It's helpful much more often than it is harmful.

Comment: Well, in production I would want that. But when I'm debugging place of error can be silently ignored and I am looking everywhere to print out nil.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the [`NSZombieEnabled`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) environment variable.

As @jtbandes said, `nil` messages are generally a good thing because you can avoid going `if (object) [object message]` and instead just use `[object message]`. But a far more important thing to watch out for is sending a message to an object that once existed but has now been freed (without the pointer being `nil`-ed out). `NSZombieEnabled` lets you find out when this has happened.

Comment: I am not getting EXE_BAD_ACCESS type of error. It's just that it's silently ignored. Does NSZomebieEnabled still help?